# Can we conclude $\prod_{\kappa \in Crd, \kappa=1}^{\kappa<\aleph_\alpha}\kappa=2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ in ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In complex analysis, there is a function called [Euler's Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Whenever given a positive integer $n+1$, it will return $n!=\prod_{i=1}^{i < n+1}i$.

I'm not sure if there is similar function for infinite cardinals such that
$$\Gamma(\aleph_\alpha)=\prod_{\kappa \in Crd, \kappa=1}^{\kappa<\aleph_\alpha}\kappa$$,
but at least we can evaluate the value of that production.

So **my question**: Is $\prod_{\kappa \in Crd, \kappa=1}^{\kappa<\aleph_\alpha}\kappa=2^{\aleph_\alpha}$?

Comment: Regarding your second proof: in general $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} \ne \beth_{\alpha}$. (But I can see what you were getting at.)

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thanks, I'm going to fix it.

Comment: You have rendered my answer useless with the two edits.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, in that time I have mistook the definition of beth numbers (mistook that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\beth_{\alpha+1}$).

Comment: Yes. I realize that. But since the question no longer refers to beth number, my answer is no longer relevant, but rather a peculiar observation.

Comment: I'm sorry about that...

Comment: I'm sorry that I have made another error: this product is the cardinal product of all positive cardinals smaller than $\aleph_\alpha$ whereas in the lemma 1 I had considered it as the cardinal product of all positive ordinals smaller than $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9017/typo-in-question-statment (Note how with your latest edit you have rendered the accepted answer somewhat irrelevant just as well, it may have been better to post a new question altogether, or in case the information given to you here was sufficient to solve it on your own, leave it with the mistakes you have made.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The study of infinite products is very subtle in general. The "factorial" is reasonably well understood. In 1925, Tarski proved that $\prod_{\xi<\beta}\aleph_\xi=(\aleph_{\bigcup \beta})^{|\bigcup\beta|}$ (for details, see [this](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/580-cardinal-arithmetic-3/) blog post of mine). Since $\prod_{n\in\omega}n=2^{\aleph_0}$, we get that 
 $$ \Gamma(\aleph_\alpha)=2^{\aleph_0}\prod_{\xi<\alpha}\aleph_\xi=2^{\aleph_0}(\aleph_{\bigcup\alpha})^{|\bigcup\alpha|}. $$
(Whether or not this is $\beth_\alpha$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in general, and clearly depends on the size of the two powers that appear in this displayed expression. As suggested in the comments, it may be worth pointing out that, for example, if $\alpha=\tau+1$ where $\tau$ is a countable successor ordinal and $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_\tau$, then $\Gamma(\aleph_\alpha)=2^{\aleph_0}\aleph_\tau^{|\tau|}=\aleph_\tau^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\tau<2^{\aleph_\tau}\le2^{\aleph_\alpha}$.)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that if the continuum is small, then it is often the case that $\aleph_\alpha^{|\alpha|}$ is much smaller than $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides, a little tip: when $\alpha=\beta+1$ then $\Gamma(\aleph_\alpha)$ should be $2^{\aleph_0}\aleph_{\beta}^{|\beta|}$.

Comment: Hehe, yes, sorry, not all ordinals are limit ordinals. :-) Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

(*Note: This answer was given to [a previous revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/362616/2) of the question*)

Certainly not. Consider a model of $\sf ZFC$ such that for every countable ordinal, $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\omega_1+1}=\beth_1$.

Let $\alpha$ be a countable ordinal and consider the following, $$\prod_{\beta<\alpha}\aleph_\beta\leq\prod_{\beta<\alpha}\aleph_\alpha = \aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_\alpha}=2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\beth_1\ll\beth_\alpha.$$