# Can we conclude that $|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|=2^{|\alpha|}$ for all infinite ordinal $\alpha$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362616/can-we-conclude-prod-kappa-in-crd-kappa-1-kappa-aleph-alpha-kappa-2), $\prod_{\kappa \in Crd, \kappa=1}^{\kappa<\aleph_\alpha}\kappa$, the cardinal product of all positive cardinals smaller than a given infinite cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$ equals to \begin{cases} 2^{\aleph_0}\aleph_\alpha^{|\alpha|}& \alpha \text{ is a limit ordinal}\\ 2^{\aleph_0}\aleph_\beta^{|\beta|}&\alpha=\beta+1\end{cases}

Similarly, let for every ordinal $\alpha$, $G(\alpha)=|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|$. That is, $G$ returns the cardinality of the Cartesian product of all positive ordinals smaller than the ordinal $\alpha$ it took.

Clearly, for all $0<\alpha<\omega$,  $G(\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha)=(\alpha-1)!$, and $G(\alpha)=1$ when $\alpha=0$.

For $\omega \le \alpha$, what I have gotten is that inequality:

**Lemma 1**
$$|\alpha|<G(\alpha) \le 2^{|\alpha|}$$

*proof.*

a)$$|\alpha|<|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|$$

$|\alpha|=\sum_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=0}^{\xi<\alpha} 1$

$=\sum_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=2}^{\xi<\alpha} 1$

$<\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=2}^{\xi<\alpha} |\xi|$ (by Koenig's Lemma)

$=|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|$

b)$$|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi| \le 2^{\alpha}$$
$|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|$

$=\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}|\xi|$

$\le \prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}|\alpha|$

$=|\alpha|^{|\alpha|}$

$=2^{|\alpha|}$

$\Box$

Now if $\mathsf{GCH}$ holds, then $|\prod_{\xi \in Ord, \xi=1}^{\xi<\alpha}\xi|=2^{|\alpha|}$ holds immediately since $|\alpha|^+=2^{|\alpha|}$. However, what about in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ but without $\mathsf{GCH}$? Can we conclude the same conclusion?

Comment: Observe that $2^\alpha=\prod_{\xi<\alpha}2$. Then obviously $2^\alpha=\prod_{\xi<\alpha}2\leq\prod_{1<\xi<\alpha}\xi$.

Comment: @Apostolos Thank you, that's all right.